# How do I properly project a list of valueMap()?

Tags: typescript, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am currently trying to project several different "properties" resulting from one vertex that I have located. Figured out 1-1, where it is missing, however multiples I run into a bit of an issue.
I was able to force a representation of individual vertices by grouping by the ID.
This works in Gremlify with a "null" key, but running similar on AWS Neptune I get this exception:

```
'{"requestId":"9dfb90b3-e479-43b1-a77b-826d71575e78","code":"InternalFailureException","detailedMessage":"Error during serialization: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap[\\"grandchild\\"])"}',
```

I know I should be sourcing this 'tag' from somewhere - just not sure how. Is it possible to even remove it?

[Gremlify Example](https://gremlify.com/clll1on3okl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to some changes in the semantics that were made in TinkerPop 3.5 to support `null` values, see [here](https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/aoaA25H1IE0/m/gTu1MqR1AQAJ).  Amazon Neptune currently supports the 3.4.11 version of TinkerPop which does not include these changes while Gremlify [supports 3.5.0](https://mobile.twitter.com/gremlify/status/1394361330929307649).

Comment: Understood a bit, but I am not sure where the current 'null' is coming from nor how I replace it out.

Comment: It is just: out("parent_to").valueMap(true).fold() , isn't it? There must be a reason that a traverser from that point is much different than from the base traverser being terminated with "toList()".

Comment: In your example you have no 'id' property on the 'grandchild' nodes but this is what you are grouping by, which is why you have the null